# How to check with pytest if one function was called inside Django form save method?

Tags: django, pytest

### What i Have

Within the save method of the form are called two functions: `generate_random_password` and `send_email`, I need to know if these functions were called because `generate_random_password` assigns a password randomly to each new created user and `send_email` sends a email notification to the user with the credentials, the password generated and the user to login. It is important to know if these functions were executed correctly within save.

```py
class UserAdminCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ()
 
    def save(self, commit: bool = True) -> U:
        user = super(UserAdminCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        data = self.cleaned_data
        # Set random password for every new user
        random_password = generate_random_password()
        user.set_password(random_password)
        # Send email confirmation with credentials to login
        email = data.get("email")
        html_message = render_to_string(
            template_name="mails/user_creation_notification.html",
            context={"email": email, "password": random_password},
        )
        # Strip the html tag. So people can see the pure text at least.
        plain_message = strip_tags(html_message)
        send_mail(
            subject="Bienvenido a TodoTránsito",
            message=plain_message,
            recipient_list=[email],
            html_message=html_message,
        )
        # Save into the DB the new user
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

### The problem

I'm using `pytest` to test my Django code, but I don't know how to assert if these functions were called.

Comment: Can't you just add a `print("in function_name")` statement inside each function?

Comment: @GAEfan I'm talking about testing, i need to assert if one functions was called inside my save form method. check `The problem` section.

Comment: Do you want to mock the functions, or do you want them to work as usual and just check if they are called?

Comment: In the first case, you can use `@mock.patch`, in the second case you could use `mocker.spy` from `pytest-mock`.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen for the first function that generates a random password I would only like to know if this function was called to know if the password was generated, to send the emails if I want to do a mock so I don't have to send the message every time I do the test and also check that this was called.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen could you explain to me in a little more detail the purpose of using each function you named and what exactly I would be testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you wrote in the comments, I would guess mocking both functions could make sense, as you probably don't really need the random password in your test. You could do something like:

```py
from unittest import mock

@mock.patch('some_module.generate_random_password', return_value='swordfish')
@mock.patch('some_module.send_mail')
def test_save_user(mocked_send_mail, mocked_generate_password):
    user_form = create_user_form()  # whatever you do to create the form in the test
    user_from.save()
    mocked_generate_password.assert_called_once()
    mocked_send_mail.assert_called_once()
    # or mocked_send_mail.assert_called_once_with(...) if you want to check the parameters it was called with
```

Note that you have to make sure to mock the correct module, e.g. the one used in the tested code (see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6)).
In this case `generate_random_password` is replaced with a mock that always returns the same password, and `send_mail` is replaced by a mock that does nothing except recording calls. Both mocks can be accessed via the arguments in the test, that are injected by the `patch` decorators (last decorator first, the argument names are arbitrary).

If you install `pytest-mock`, you get the `mocker` fixture, that gives you the same functionality and more. The same code would like like this:

```py
def test_save_user(mocker):
    mocked_generate_password = mocker.patch('some_module.generate_random_password', return_value='swordfish')
    mocked_send_mail = mocker.patch('some_module.send_mail')
    user_form = create_user_form()  # whatever you do to create the form in the test
    user_from.save()
    mocked_generate_password.assert_called_once()
    mocked_send_mail.assert_called_once()
```

If you now want to use the real `generate_random_password`, but still want to see if it was called, you can use `mocker.spy` instead:

```py
def test_save_user(mocker):
    mocked_generate_password = mocker.spy(some_module, 'generate_random_password')
    mocked_send_mail = mocker.patch('some_module.send_mail')
    user_form = create_user_form()  # whatever you do to create the form in the test
    user_from.save()
    mocked_generate_password.assert_called_once()
    mocked_send_mail.assert_called_once()
```

Note that you can achieve the same with `unittest.mock.patch.object`, but less convenient, in my opinion.

Comment: When you use `mocked_generate_password`, what do you mean?

Comment: This is the mock for `generate_random_password`- I adapted the answer to make this more clear. In the example it is configured to always return "swordfish".

Comment: In the second example with `pyest-mock`, you use `mocked_generate_password.assert_called_once()` i need to store `mocker.patch` in a variable like `mocked_send_mail = mocker.patch("app_todotransito_co.users.forms.send_mail")` to be able to assert this method like `mocked_send_mail.assert_called_once()` because when I run the test this thrown `NameError: name 'generate_random_password' is not defined`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, forgot to adapt this. Not at a PC, so I make mistakes...

Comment: With this, test pass, but in the coverage report should appear this lines as tested or I'm wrong?  because they appear to me as if they're untested.

Comment: The calling code should be shown as tested, the functions replaced by a mock (like `send_mail`) themselves not.

Comment: What about if I want to know if `send_email` and  `render_to_string` was called with the correct arguments. I need to be shure that html_message was generated with the correct information(the email and the random password) this data is going to be used for the user to log in, and I need to test if the email has this information in its body

Comment: You can use `assert_called_once_with` or `assert_called_with` in this case (as I wrote in a comment in the answer).